# Parsing for html tag with specific attribute in Swift

Tags: html, parsing, attributes, swift4, xcode9

Is there a method to parse an HTML link for tags with **specific attributes**?

Right now I use the following code to get the content of the page (with SwiftSoup):

```
    // Checking if MyLink is working
    guard let myURL = URL(string: MyLink) else {                                                 // myURL needed only temporarly
        print("Error: \(MyLink) doesn't seem to be a valid URL")
        return
    }

    // Getting all content of website for a specific link
    do {
        MyLinkContent = try String(contentsOf: myURL, encoding: .ascii)
    } catch let error {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
```

After I get the content I can save all links in an array, for example with this code:

```
        // Searching for all links in the content of the URL and creating elements
        guard let linkElements: Elements = try? SwiftSoup.parse(MyLinkContent).select("a")  else {return}
        //  Now all elements are printed into an array
        for element: Element in linkElements.array(){
            MyLinkArray.append("\(element)")
        }
```

This results in an array with all links of the website.

My question however is, say for example the homepage has a lot of tags with the following format:

```
- Things I don't need especially a lot of <tr tags but with other attributes I don't need
- <tr id="row_">"TheContentINeed"</tr>
- <tr id="row_">"TheContentINeed"</tr> 
- <tr id="row_">"TheContentINeed"</tr> 
- <tr id="row_">"TheContentINeed"</tr> 
- <tr id="row_">"TheContentINeed"</tr> 
- More Things I don't need specially a lot of <tr tags but with other attributes I don't need
```

I would like to save all contents in an array, but only the tags with the attribute "id"

Any ideas?
I would prefer to use SwiftSoup (if possible) again.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Combine your CSS selectors. See Example project from more.

```
// Searching for all links in the content of the URL and creating elements
guard let linkElements: Elements = try? SwiftSoup.parse(MyLinkContent).select("a tr[id="row"]")  else {return}
//  Now all elements are printed into an array
for element: Element in linkElements.array(){
   MyLinkArray.append("\(element)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try it in the next days and keep you updated!